# Should I clean up my old table statistics?

Tags: sql-server, statistics

I've been cleaning up my indexes but now realized I have over 150 statistics that remain that are not used.  Should I drop them?  I'm not noticing any performance issues from them.  I have 9 indexes and 159 statistics.

Comment: How are you figuring out if they're used or not?

Comment: Are these column statistics? Where are you seeing these? What is your concern with them? As Erik asked, how do you know they're not used?

Comment: The majority of them are named the same as indexes we dropped several years ago.  I need do more research on the others use and column vs table

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/09/09/sql-server-auto-statistics-cleanup/). 
I think it will answer your questions and give you the tools to deal with over-inflated number of auto-statistics.
The author suggests dropping ALL auto-created stats occasionally, as the one that are required will be recreated when the first query that needs it is executed. It explains the risks / benefits.